# Ansible: Comparing a String with a register

Tags: ansible

This script was intended to obtain the time zone on each server and store it in a register. After that I would compare the time zone stored in the register with the variable, time_zone, to see if all the servers are in PDT time. The second task shoulds print out all the servers that are not in PDT time, but the logic is completely opposite of what I intended. Currently, the second task runs when TZ != PDT and skips when TZ == PDT. I am running this locally and I'm currently in PDT time zone.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    time_zone: 'PDT'

  tasks:

  - name: Find the servers that are not in PDT time zone.
    shell: date | awk '{print $5}'
    register: TZ
  - debug: msg={{TZ.stdout}}

  - name: Display the servers that are not in PDT time zone. 
    shell: echo $HOSTNAME
    when: TZ != time_zone
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid `shell` when built-in methods available:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    time_zone: 'PDT'
  tasks:
    - name: Display the servers that are not in PDT time zone. 
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
      when: ansible_date_time.tz != time_zone
```

Comment: Go with this answer instead of mine.  Much cleaner :)

Comment: Thank you very much, Konstantin. I'm curious how you found the other modules like "ansbile_hostname" and "ansible_date_time" because they are not located in the online documentation. – Randall

Comment: These are "gathered facts". You can see them for example with a command `ansible localhost -m setup`.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the desired logic correctly all you need to do is use the stdout of your registered variable inside your conditional.

```
- name: Display the servers that are not in PDT time zone. 
  shell: echo $HOSTNAME
  when: TZ.stdout != time_zone
```